# (HTML) storing links in an central file

Tags: html, xml

i wanna do a html but i don't know how to store links in an extra file.
The code is:

```
<a title="DESCR" href="LINK" target="_blank" style="color: white">NAME</a>
```

i want to get the LINK in an central File. Optional if its possible, the Name too.
i tried for the last 2 Days and found nothing that works.
i tried to create an css for this but css is only for design purposes...

does anyone have an idea how to do it?

Comment: you can't do that in html, you will have to use scripting langauge such as php or asp.net

Comment: do i have to install extra software? i hope not

Comment: i heard that i can include an Javascript, that should put out the code

Answer (score 0):

You can define your data in javascript and use a little script that will use the data to create the link-elements for you.

Here the `linksData` is an array of urls. You can add more infos when you use an array of objects (json). The script goes through that array and creates a new anchor for each url.

```js
var linksData = ["https://example.com", "https://stackoverflow.com"];

var linksList = document.getElementById("links");

for (var i = 0; i < linksData.length; ++i) {
    var listItem = document.createElement("li");
    var anchor = document.createElement("a");

    anchor.setAttribute("href", linksData[i]);
    var text = document.createTextNode(linksData[i]);

    anchor.appendChild(text);
    listItem.appendChild(anchor);
    linksList.appendChild(listItem);
}
```

```html
<ul id="links">


</ul>
```

To include an external javascript in your html you will tyically add

```
 <script src="myScript.js"></script>
```

to the `head` section of your html.